# How to unset the element from an array of objects

Tags: php

I have an array of operating systems ($os2) and i would like to remove all elements from array $phones , which dont have one of these operating systems. So i did this, but for some reason it's not working...

```
$os2 = array("BlackBerry", "Android");
if(count($os2)!=0)
{
    for($i = 0; $i<count($phones); $i++)
    {
        if(!in_array($phones[$i]->os, $os2))
        {
            unset($phones[$i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is one element from the phones array:

```
[0] => Equipment Object
        (
            [carrierDescription:Equipment:private] => T-Mobile
            [carrierId:Equipment:private] => 59
            [manufacturerID:Equipment:private] => 13
            [manufacturerName:Equipment:private] => BlackBerry
            [manufacturerCode:Equipment:private] => Curve 9360  
            [productId:Equipment:private] => 60558
            [currentEquipmentID:Equipment:private] => 29305
            [equipmentName:Equipment:private] => BlackBerry Curve 9360 Black
            [equipmentType:Equipment:private] => Smartphone
            [equipmentShortDescription:Equipment:private] =>  
            [equipmentLongDescription:Equipment:private] => The BlackBerry Curve 9360 for T-Mobile is the next Curve in BlackBerry's line of smartphones. Running the latest BlackBerry 7 operating system and utilizing the powerful BlackBerry 7 Webkit-browser, the BlackBerry Curve 9360 provides an intuitive smartphone experience, perfect for those who depend on their smartphone to keep their personal and work lives organized. Encased in a sleek package, including a wide 2.4 inch screen, full QWERTY keyboard and navigation track-pad, the BlackBerry Curve 9360 is ideal for efficient mobile communication. This new smartphone is also equipped with essential smartphone features such as a 5 megapixel camera with flash, video recorder, and WiFi connectivity for voice and data for a premium smartphone experience, The new Curve 9360 delivers the world's best mobile communications and social experiences with the latest release of BlackBerry Messenger, or BBM. 
            [sugRetailPrice:Equipment:private] => 400
            [displayPrice:Equipment:private] => $999.99
            [equipmentPrice:Equipment:private] => 0
            [numericCost:Equipment:private] => 0
            [rebateAmount:Equipment:private] => $0.00
            [priceAfterRebate:Equipment:private] => Free
            [rebateDescription:Equipment:private] => Free Gift
            [equipmentImageFileSmall:Equipment:private] => images/phones/60558_s.jpg
            [equipmentImageFileMedium:Equipment:private] => images/phones/60558_m.jpg
            [equipmentImageFileLarge:Equipment:private] => images/phones/60558_l.jpg
            [manufacturerLogo:Equipment:private] => _images/logos/manufacturers/selected_manu_blackberry.gif
            [purchaseMode:Equipment:private] => Add a Line
            [productLink:Equipment:private] => r.aspx?p=BlackBerry%20Curve%209360%20Black&c=T-Mobile&r=wowphonefinder&mode=1&s=1
            [upc:Equipment:private] => 610214626622
            [compatibleAccessoriesPageURL:Equipment:private] => DeviceSpecificAccessories.aspx?referringdomain=wowphonefinder&refcode1=standarddatafeed&refcode2=&productid=60558
            [mods:Equipment:private] => 
            [os:Equipment:private] => BlackBerry
            [tethering:Equipment:private] => 
            [hotspot:Equipment:private] => 
            [html:Equipment:private] => HTML
            [triG:Equipment:private] => 3G
            [fourG:Equipment:private] => 
            [fiveMP:Equipment:private] => 
            [bluetooth:Equipment:private] => bluetooth
            [camera:Equipment:private] => camera
            [mail:Equipment:private] => mail
            [gps:Equipment:private] => gps
            [international:Equipment:private] => international
            [mp3:Equipment:private] => MP3
            [vcast:Equipment:private] => 
            [wifi:Equipment:private] => wifi
            [tscreen:Equipment:private] => 
            [appstore:Equipment:private] => appstore
            [fcamera:Equipment:private] => 
            [ptt:Equipment:private] => 
            [rugged:Equipment:private] => 
            [sbluetooth:Equipment:private] => 
            [qwerty:Equipment:private] => qwerty
            [nocolor:Equipment:private] => Curve 9360  
            [colors:Equipment:private] => Black Black
            [hasShort:Equipment:private] => 
            [hasReview:Equipment:private] => 
            [hasAlternative:Equipment:private] => 
            [hasAlternativeExpert:Equipment:private] => 
            [order:Equipment:private] => 
            [review:Equipment:private] => 
            [id] => 260
        )
```

Btw...its working this way, but i will be really happy if someone have the solution without using the another variable, just with unset method...

```
if(count($os2)!=0)
{
    $ph = array();
    foreach($phones as $phone)
    {
        foreach($os2 as $o)
        {
            if($phone->os == $o)
            {array_push($ph,$phone);}
        }
    }
    $phones = $ph;
}
```

Does anybody see what am I doing wrong? :)
Thanks for your answers...

Comment: What is it ? $os2 = ("BlackBerry", "Android");??? is it an array?

Comment: @user855705 **absolutely NOTHING** :-P see my answer.

Comment: `$os2 = ("BlackBerry", "Android");` results in `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in...`

Comment: Additionally, dont put that `count` in the `for` loop, as it will execute on every iteration of the loop, just assign the count to a variable above it and pass that instead.

Comment: Guys, $os2 = ("BlackBerry", "Android"); is my mistake while i was writing this question in there. Its not like that in my code...

Answer (score 2):

This: `$os2 = ("BlackBerry", "Android");` is **NOT** an array.

I am not even sure what it is. PHP will probably throw errors and warnings at you about it if you had them on.

An array in php is formed like this:

```
$os2 = array("BlackBerry", "Android");
```

Comment: yeah sorry i made a mistake... its already like that in my code... Actually that $os2 array is filled with array_push method. But still i am getting phones with different operating systems...

Answer (score 0):

```
$os2 = ("BlackBerry", "Android");
```

is a syntax error. It should be:

```
$os2 = array("BlackBerry", "Android");
```

To unset a particular array element by its value:

```
if (($key = array_search('Android', $os2, TRUE)) !== FALSE) {
    unset($os2[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the line:

```
[os:Equipment:private] => BlackBerry
```

You see that `os` is a private variable, so you can't get it by using `$object->os`, you will need to use it's getter.

Comment: Friend, that part is good, i've already tested that by echo-ing the $phone[$i], just it wont unset that object for some reason... :(